# Common web app code base

Tags: code

There are a bunch of very similar RE search sites out there. I would not be surprised if a lot of them started out from the same code base. Does anyone know if these are all custom built, or if some of them spawn from a common code base?

www.estately.com

www.sawbuck.com

www.movoto.com

www.windermere.com

www.homes.com

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

No. They aren't all from the same code base.

Interestingly, at least two of them are ColdFusion based: the Windermere one and the homes.com one. The URL schema is very different, though. I think the homes.com one may be using a ColdFusion framework (Fusebox?), but maybe the Windermere one is not.

In contrast the movoto.com site uses ASP.NET (.aspx), as is sawbuck.com. They're very different from each other, structure-wise.

I could not determine (quickly) what Estately is using. FWIW, I thought their site was more polished and quite modern in comparison to the others.

If there is a common thread, it's the data. There are a number of APIs they could be using that are common, despite the lack of commonality in the programming. Here is a site that lists web API available for consumption:

http://www.programmableweb.com/